# Django Rest Framework get all options for choice field

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am wondering if it is possible to write an API which returns all possible options for a choice field.

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    sample_choices = (
        ('1', 'One'),
        ('2', 'Two'),
        ....
    )

    choice_value = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=sample_choices)
```

I want an API which will return all the possible choices that a field has.

Reason i want this is to avoid duplication in my frontend code, where i want these fields in a dropdown in a form.

Comment: i am using react for frontend, so cant use django templates to render the choices

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it with an API View. Was fairly simple in the end. :)

```
class ChoiceListView(views.APIView):      
    def get(self, request):         
        choices = []         
        choice_dict = dict(SampleModel.sample_choices)          

        for k, v in choice_dict.items():             
            value = {'key': k, 'value': v}             
            choices.append(value)         
        return response.Response(choices, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all choice in your view using,

```
>>> SampleModel.options.field.choices
(('1', 'One'), ('2', 'Two'))
```